# Maximum Row Size with VarChar(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I know if I have a table with 10 varchar(1000) columns and I actually put 1000 characters in each of those columns and try to INSERT that row I'll get an error due to SQL Server's row limitation of 8K. However, if those columns are defined as varchar(max) would I get an error?

If not then what about the following scenario:
I have 8 varchar(1000) columns that I max out plus I have 2 varchar(max) columns all on one table with some characters in them. Would I get an error?

I think the answer is no I wouldn't get an error in either case, but I need to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original assumption is incorrect since SQL Server 2005.

The `varchar(1000)` case would end up with some columns stored offrow so there is no reason to declare 2 of your columns as `varchar(max)` rather than `varchar(1000)` just to avoid this non existent issue.

There is a performance overhead to storing data offrow as SQL Server needs to follow pointers from the data page to the off row page so if you expect this to be a common case you might consider vertically partitioning the table in some way.

Comment: I use varchar(max) a lot for long description columns where I don't want to limit the amount of characters a user can choose to key. I don't know that any of them have exceeded 8K yet, but I haven't noticed any performance hit. I imagine the majority of the performance overhead is if you actually have >8K in the column. Thanks for the quick answer.